# Squirrel - DB2 : Connection to the data server failed. The IBM Data Server for JDBC and SQLJ license was invalid

Tags: db2, database-connection, squirrel-sql

I am using squirrel to connect to DB2 database.

I am able to successfully connect to one of our DB2 databases. But when I create a new connection to point to another db2 database, I get the below mentioned error.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc]...... Connection to the data server failed. The IBM Data Server for JDBC and SQLJ license was invalid 
or was not activated for the DB2 for z/OS subsystem. If you are connecting directly to 
the data server and using DB2 Connect Unlimited Edition for System z, perform the 
activation step by running the activation program in the license activation kit.  
If you are using any other edition of DB2 Connect, obtain the license file, 
db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar, from the license activation kit, and follow the installation 
directions to include the license file in the class path. ERRORCODE=-4230, SQLSTATE=42968
```

I also tried to create a new Driver to use in Squirrel, But that too doesnot work.
I have  db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar available in the same folder where I pointed my driver jar.

I am really surprised why one connection to DB2 works and the other doesn't work.

Comment: Are both databases on z/OS?

Answer (score 1):

db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar must be in CLASSPATH. Check db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar in Java Class Path or Extra Class Path in driver properties.